# How to add whitespace between components in `apex:form`?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

How to add space between two inputText components in `apex:form`?

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:inputText value="{!inputValue1}"/>
    ... Add space here ...
    <apex:inputText value="{!inputValue2}"/>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use normal html tags like `<br/>` or `&nbsp;`.  You could also use the styleClass attribute and use css to add paddings or margins as well.

See here for more info on styling in SF

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_styling_custom.htm

Comment: HTML collapses whitespace.  You can do as the ninja suggested or use `&nbsp;` -- a space character that will not collapse.

Comment: Yes, &nbsp; is a good alternative as well

Comment: I tried `nbsp;`, and it works great! Thanks @PhilR and @SF_Ninja!

Comment: No prob, glad to help

Comment: I have a <apex:outputlabel value="<Need to Insert Blank space here>"/> ? How can i do that any idea?